How to proceed if someone is working on an idea you shared with them without telling you?
I discovered someone working under the ex-boss of my boss is working on an idea I discussed with them a few months ago (something I wanted to do and was happy to collaborate on, for more manpower).
The idea is not revolutionary. But it is something I ran by some people to check if it made sense (even my boss, though I am not sure if they remember or even care).
Though, that person (more junior than myself) is working on something I proposed. They have worked on something tangential, and this was the reason for which I was discussing with them. At the time, they told me it was a nice idea and worth trying (it seems even their boss was fine).
Actually their boss was talking about the projects of this person. I did not say anything at the moment, but mentioned later I discussed with their associate that idea to which I had done some simple crunching of numbers.
Now, I find myself in a very weird position.

what if they completely forgot that I told them about this?
what if their boss, someone really expert, mentioned this to them?
what if they just went ahead, and took the idea?

In all of the cases, what pisses me off is that they did not reach out to me.

Shall I play dumb and contact them and ask how it is going to see if they wanna do the project together?
Shall I talk to them directly by email?
Shall I tell my boss? Especially when things are unclear I am not sure it is the right idea.

I tried to make a mental table of the cases, and I feel the best way is to write them a direct email mentioning the fact of not contacting me. But then, I am not sure how to proceed. My goal is still to collaborate, as the goal is to do science.
It is not the first time that someone works on something I suggested (or maybe I wanted to do myself sometime in the future).
I am a junior scientist, and need to make my name. I think collaborating is really important. But I a keep getting amazed by the behavior of other junior scientists (and half of the time I am amazed, by senior ones).

EDIT:
(changed title to reflect better the question)
Thanks everybody for your answers. I think in the end I was just a bit upset for not being contacted, as at the time I suggested to collaborate. Obviously nobody owns ideas, and hard work is more important. And kudos to them for going on.
Your input was very appreciated. Hard work is one of the most important things in the end of the day, and not just talking.

Are you working on this idea?

Are you working in industry or academia or at a lab or … ?

When you say "boss" do you mean your doctoral advisor and their doctoral advisor  or some employment relationship other than that?

Did you talk with any of the people involved in this about collaborating when you discussed the idea with them a few months ago?

Your post might benefit from proofreading for grammar and spelling.

yes. I literally suggested to collaborate (but could not have time to do this at the time. still not now, but in a couple of months yes, as I lack man power) WhatTheDuck
I am working in academia @Buffy . I am a postdoc. The other person a phd student.
It is not really about the idea (anyway, I have and have many more). But about the behavior of people that go to do behind your back something you suggest. If this is the right way to look at things. I know these kind of things can happen, but I would like to see if there is a way I can hold my ground here. (if it makes sense).

@QuestioningAcademia It really sounds like you just said "It would be pretty cool if X, Y and Z," and the PhD student said, "oh yeah, that's a good idea" and added it to what they were working on. Coming at this as "someone stole my idea" is likely to be counterproductive.

In answer to the question "How to proceed if I think someone stole my idea" - there's probably not a whole lot to be done here.
The fact that you discussed an idea with someone a few months ago does not mean that they are required to contact you and work with you while they investigate that idea, even if you suggested a collaboration, particularly because you were not planning on working on it then. Research is fast-paced. If you have a good idea and talk about it with other researchers, it is unreasonable to expect them to ignore that idea for however long it takes you to get around to actually doing something with it. If you were showing them your prior work on this and they were incorporating it into their own work, that would be a different, more actionable situation, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.
As to the rest of your post - if you want to collaborate with this person on this idea, then simply email them and tell them that you heard they were working on this idea, you are also really interested in it (per that conversation you had a few months ago), and would they be open to collaborating on it. Emailing them and starting off hostile off the bat ("Why didn't you contact me about this idea?") is not conducive to making people want to work with you, no matter how much in the right (you feel) you are in the situation.

And you don't need to "play dumb".

I'll note here since this answer covers most of my points, that you don't and can't "own" ideas, so no one can "steal" them from you.

I agree to some extent. But not completely. Getting the best ideas is also a skill itself that might have taken lots of hard work. And it is important for science that you can 'bounce' ideas to get other's feedback without fearing that they'd just run off with it. Imo, if they were aware still that it was your idea, they should offer you to collaborate or at least acknowledge you. On the other hand, sometimes, the time can just be right for several people to have the idea at the same time

I have similar fears with you when discussing potential project ideas with more senior researchers, especially when looking for postdoc positions, where one usually proposes an idea to work on during the interview/application, but there is no guarantee that they will get an offer for a position.
The issue with "ideas" is that once they are out no one owns them.
Very often I will read a paper and be enthusiastic about a new idea the paper proposes, then forget about it, and then "come up" with same idea the paper proposed 6 months later, only to later find out that this was not my idea, but something I read about.
What I mean with this, is that once you discuss or read about an idea, you accumulate that new piece of information in your internal knowledge system or way of thinking. If the idea for example proposes route III for going from result A to result B, and until now you only knew the tedious routes I and II to connect A to B, that avenue has been opened in your head from now on. You saw an alternative way of thinking for tackling this problem and you can't unsee it.
A few months later you may forget about the source of the idea and whether someone told you about it, the identity of the person, or whether you came up alone with it.
In your current situation I totally understand your frustration. However  I would propose to contact the people to work on this, remind that you discussed something similar with them, and that you would be willing to collaborate  because you have similar interests and you were also about to work on the same thing.
Often someone comes up with an idea, not because they were the only person who could think about it, but because the substrate in terms of prior work is there to facilitate the emergence of this idea. Thus is quite common that often a couple of people around the world (who do not even know each other) come up with the same or very similar idea to tackle a problem simultaneously. That doesn't mean that someone stole the idea from the other, but that the route for that idea has been carved out from prior work and it was the right time for that idea to come out.
I mention this because it could be also probable that the former boos of your current boss was playing in their head with similar thought before you discussed your idea with them.

Ideas alone are worthless.
Simply put, people have a million ideas every day - whether those are ideas for artistic endeavours like books or video games they think would be cool to make, or ideas for scientific investigations.
Ideas alone have no real value. If you're open to them, you'll be bombarded with a torrent of them from people.
The thing that is actually valuable isn't the idea itself, but the hard work spent making the idea into a reality, and the skills required to do so. It doesn't matter how cool your idea for a painting is if you can't paint and don't put the effort into actually painting.
